# How to correctly download WWDC videos from iTunes U?

Tags: macos, itunes, itunes-u

I am trying to download WWDC videos from iTunes U. When I click on "Get" it starts downloading but after the download completes it disappears from iTunes U collection.

I tried to download it from my new MacBook Pro, OSX Lion and iTunes 10.5 .

When I downloaded the same video from my office mac running OSX Snow Leopard 10.6.7 and iTunes 10.4 everything worked.

What could be wrong in this case? Should I wait for new iTunes update?

Comment: I get the same error on my machine. I monitored available disk space in finder when the download finished and it seems like iTunes just deletes the file as the disk space increases to previous value when it is finished. OS X 10.7.2 and iTunes 10.5.2 (newest to date)

Comment: yes I got the same issue on my machine with iTunes U downloads too

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and setting iTunes to run in 32-bit mode fixed it for me. There might be an issue with the video encoding on some of the older WWDC videos like the "Working with Core Data" video that can be found at the [Apple developer video site](https://developer.apple.com/videos/) under iOS.

**To set iTunes to run in 32-bit mode:**

- Quit iTunes.
- Open your applications folder and control-click or right-click on the iTunes icon.
- Select "Get Info".
- Click the checkbox next to "Open in 32-bit mode".
- Open iTunes again and you should be able to download the videos to your collection.

When you are done with your videos, you can always reverse these steps to set iTunes back to 64-bit mode.

Comment: This worked for me - how frigging absolutely lame!

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem when downloading videos from iTunes U.

While an update might be required to properly download videos, what I've done was to "Watch" the download progress window (I.E. I kept the downloads window from iTunes open while everything was downloading.) And for some reason, after the download, the file gets processed and is available for viewing.